# Processing key and value pair using yq

Tags: yaml, jq, yq

I'm new to for yq parser tool, I'm am trying convert json into yaml

**Input json**

```json
{
  "name": "Fruit",
  "values": [
    "banana"
  ]
}
```

**Output Yaml**

```yaml
{
Fruit : banana
}
```

How can I achieve this result using yq

could you please suggest on this.

command I was trying

```
yq -r '(.name):(.[].values)' keys.yaml
```

Comment: That not valid YAML as output. Please clarify. Also mention what you need if there are multiple elements in the values array.

Comment: I think you're just looking for `yq -r '{ (.name): .values[0] }'`

Comment: What do you want when there are multiple values?

Comment: `.[].values` -> `.values[]`

Comment: @0stone0 thanks for your response 
In my case there is one to one mapping between key and value, so there won't be multiple values inside values array.

Comment: YAML is a superset of JSON, so the question seems to be how to turn the given JSON into `{"Fruit":"banana"}` and one possible answer is `.Fruit = .values[0]`

Comment: This  is the yaml output of actual file


yq  '.' keys.yaml
---
argon :["0.1.75"] nginx :["0.1.62"] alpine :["0.1.162"] device-service :["0.1.198"] resource-service :["0.1.223"] tunnel-service :["0.1.173"]


If i'm trying to access any value from key it's not working
yq  '.argon' keys.yaml

Comment: @Amey it's useless to add unformatted code (of a whitespace-sensitive language!) in a comment. Please [edit] your question to include additional details. And I'm confused: the question states the input is JSON, but the comment shows the input is YAML?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, now I am able to produce required output in yaml, next question is how to read the output using yq

Comment: keys.yaml   
`argon :["0.1.75"] nginx :["0.1.62"] alpine :["0.1.162"] device-service :["0.1.198"] resource-service :["0.1.223"] tunnel-service :["0.1.173"]`

Comment: what I am trying  `yq  '.argon' keys.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to happen when there are multiple values for your key?

If you only want to take the first value, then several equivalent solutions exist:

- `{ (.name): .values[0] }`
- `[.value = .values[0]] | from_entries`